# How to change the Date format that we get from text field "16-JUL-2010" to 20100716 using php or using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

How to change the Date format that we get from text field "16-JUL-2010"  to 20100716 using php or using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('Ymd',strtotime("16-JUL-2010"));
```

Comment: Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly Really Reallly  THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS THANKS - WrikKen

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-y', $_GET['date']);
echo $date->format('Ymd');
```

Comment: FWIW, the DateTime constructor takes any valid [strtotime](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) string, so you don't really *need* to createFromFormat.

Comment: Iam Using 5.2.13 Version Which doesnot support DateTime()

Comment: @Someone: Yes, it does. It's just the `createFromFormat()` method that was added in 5.3. You can pass the date to the constructor instead as Charles said.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you'd be best off using the [Date.js library](http://www.datejs.com/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    d = Date.parse("16-JUL-2010")
    d.toString('yyyyMMdd');
</script>
```